# Laravel Database [postgres] not configured

Tags: database, laravel

Can anyone help me to fix this problem please
the error is database [postgres] not configured.

here is my .env file :

```
   DB_CONNECTION=postgres
   DB_HOST=localhost
   DB_PORT=5432
   DB_DATABASE=referentiel
   DB_USERNAME=postgres
   DB_PASSWORD=postgres
```

and here is my database.php:

```
  'default' => 'postgres',

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => 'referentiel',
        'username' => env('postgres', ''),
        'password' => env('postgres', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `default` parameter in your `config` to match the name of your postgres connection - `pgsql` in your case:

```
'default' => 'pgsql',
```

And put correct database parameters in your `.env` file.

Comment: it's settled but i got an other error "could not find driver" do you have any idea ?

Comment: Does your server actually have the postgres extension enabled in your php.ini?

Comment: Like patricksweeney said, you probably need to install the drivers for your PHP version [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927225/how-to-enable-postgresql-driver-for-pdo-for-php-7) should get you on the right track, but I've never used it myself and can't help you with that part.

Answer (score 2):

Try to edit your `.env`

From: `DB_CONNECTION=postgres`

To: `DB_CONNECTION=pgsql`

Comment: try to change 'default' => 'pgsql` as @devk mentioned

Comment: if that's not working try to exec command : php artisan config:cache

Comment: This commend is profoundly useful in case you are dealing with multi-containered application.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem in php.ini if you use xampp open app xampp > config > php.ini

find   `;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`
       `;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll`

delete `;`

change `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll`
`extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll`